# Creating custom json objects using changeable number of variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, javascript-objects

I have this json object:

```
[
  {
    "trip": [
      {
        "place": {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "New York",
        },
        "group": 1
      }
  },
  ...
]
```

I can have a N number of groups, so i need to create an array of objects like this:

```
[
   {
     "group1": "New York",
     "group2": "Los Angeles",
     "group3": "Rome",
     ...
   }
]
```

Each group is called groupX where X is a number taken from every "group" instance in every object in the first array and his value must be taken from "name" instance in every object in the first array.

How can i do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In JS, `obj.property1` is equivalent to `obj['property' + 1]` or `obj['prop' + 'erty1']`.

Comment: Do you really want as output an array that contains a single object where the properties of that single object are the names of all the groups?

Comment: Thank you very much @hugo for your help, problem fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map()` is handy for getting an array of results, applying a function to each element of an existing array. Something like this:

```js
var obj = [{
    "trip": [{
      "place": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "New York",
      },
      "group": 1
    }]
  },
  {
    "trip": [{
      "place": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "london",
      },
      "group": 2
    }]
  },
  {
    "trip": [{
      "place": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "tokyo",
      },
      "group": 3
    }]
  },
]
var result = obj.map((array_element) => {
  let group = "group" + String(array_element['trip'][0]['group'])
  let place = String(array_element['trip'][0]['place']['name'])
  let to_return = {};
  to_return[group] = place
  return to_return;
})
console.log(result)
/*
[
{ "group1": "New York" },
{ "group2": "london" },
{ "group3": "tokyo" }
]
*/
```

Comment: 1. Why the String(...) conversions? Both seem redundant. 2. Just write `return {[group]: place}` instead of the last three lines. 3. OP asked for a single obj that has N keys "groupN", not N objs with each one key.

Comment: @Lorenzo if you're after the above as an array with a single element .reduce() might be better. It's not super clear what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
let data = [
  { 'trip': [{ 'place': { 'id': 8, 'name': 'New York' }, 'group': 1 }] },
  { 'trip': [{ 'place': { 'id': 9, 'name': 'Los Angeles' }, 'group': 2 }] },
  { 'trip': [{ 'place': { 'id': 10, 'name': 'Rome' }, 'group': 3 }] },
]

let grouped = data.reduce(function(grouped, current) {
  grouped['group' + current.trip[0].group] = current.trip[0].place.name;

  return grouped;
}, {})

console.log(grouped);
```